# Casimir Invariants within the universal enveloping algebra

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-algebras

I've been asked to determine the eigenvalue of the Casimir invariant $I_2$ on any irreducible module with highest weight $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n)$, where;
$$I_m = \sum^{n}_{k=1}A^{m}_{kk}$$With $A^{m}_{kk}$ being a representation for the diagonal elements of the universal enveloping algebra $U(gl(n))$. I'm not really sure where to start with it, and any help would be fantastic.